# How can I check if a string contains a character in C#?

Tags: c#, string

Is there a function I can apply to a string that will return true of false if a string contains a character.

I have strings with one or more character options such as:

```
var abc = "s";
var def = "aB";
var ghi = "Sj";
```

What I would like to do for example is have a function that would return true or false if the above contained a lower or upper case "s".

```
if (def.Somefunction("s") == true) { }
```

Also in C# do I need to check if something is true like this or could I just remove the "== true" ?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can use the extension method [`.Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.100).aspx) from the namespace `System.Linq`:

```cs
using System.Linq;

    ...

    if (abc.ToLower().Contains('s')) { }
```

And also, to check if a boolean expression is true, you don't need `== true`

Since the `Contains` method is an extension method, my solution might be confusing. Here are two versions that don't require you to add `using System.Linq;`:

```cs
if (abc.ToLower().IndexOf('s') != -1) { }

// or:

if (abc.IndexOf("s", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1) { }
```

**Update**

If you want to, you can write your own extensions method for easier reuse:

```cs
public static class MyStringExtensions
{
    public static bool ContainsAnyCaseInvariant(this string haystack, char needle)
    {
        return haystack.IndexOf(needle, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1;
    }
    
    public static bool ContainsAnyCase(this string haystack, char needle)
    {
        return haystack.IndexOf(needle, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1;
    }
}
```

Then you can call them like this:

```cs
if (def.ContainsAnyCaseInvariant('s')) { }
// or
if (def.ContainsAnyCase('s')) { }
```

In most cases when dealing with user data, you actually want to use `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` *(or the `ContainsAnyCase` extension method)*, because that way you let the system handle upper/lowercase issues, which depend on the language. When dealing with computational issues, like names of HTML tags and so on, you want to use the invariant culture.

For example: In Turkish, the uppercase letter `I` in lowercase is `ı` *(without a dot)*, and not `i` *(with a dot)*.

Comment: Hmm, I don't find a overload of String.Contains that takes a char argument.

Comment: @ScottSmith This is an extension method defined in [System.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx). You need to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I prefer to use `str.IndexOf('s') >= 0` but it's probably just a stylistic difference. It makes more sense to me when reading for comprehension.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `IndexOf` method, which has a suitable overload for string comparison types:

```
if (def.IndexOf("s", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) ...
```

Also, you would not need the `== true`, since an if statement only expects an expression that evaluates to a `bool`.

Answer (score 5):

Use the function String.Contains();

an example call,

```
abs.Contains("s"); // to look for lower case s
```

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) is more from MSDN.

Comment: This does not answer the OPs question - they wanted to know whether an upper or lowercase "s" was present - your solution would only evaluate to true if a lowercase "s" was in the string.

Comment: If you want to check if its either upper or lower case then you can just convert both strings to lower case before checking them:

```
string abc = "S";
```

```
Console.WriteLine(abc.ToLower().Contains("S".ToLower()));
```

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

```
var abc = "sAb";
bool exists = abc.IndexOf("ab", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1;
```

Answer (score 3):

It will be hard to work in C# without knowing how to work with strings and booleans. But anyway:

```
        String str = "ABC";
        if (str.Contains('A'))
        { 
            //...
        }

        if (str.Contains("AB"))
        { 
            //...
        }
```

Comment: MSDN doesn't list a Contains method that accepts a character, like in your first example. To get that syntax you'd need to use LINQ or write your own Contains extension.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool containsCharacter = test.IndexOf("s", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own extention method if you plan to use this a lot.

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static bool ContainsInvariant(this string sourceString, string filter)
    {
        return sourceString.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(filter);
    }
}
```

example usage:

```
public class test
{
    public bool Foo()
    {
        const string def = "aB";
        return def.ContainsInvariant("s");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

here is an example what most of have done

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Test("Dot Net Perls");
        Test("dot net perls");
    }

    static void Test(string input)
    {
        Console.Write("--- ");
        Console.Write(input);
        Console.WriteLine(" ---");
        //
        // See if the string contains 'Net'
        //
        bool contains = input.Contains("Net");
        //
        // Write the result
        //
        Console.Write("Contains 'Net': ");
        Console.WriteLine(contains);
        //
        // See if the string contains 'perls' lowercase
        //
        if (input.Contains("perls"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Contains 'perls'");
        }
        //
        // See if the string contains 'Dot'
        //
        if (!input.Contains("Dot"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doesn't Contain 'Dot'");
        }
    }
}
```