# Check What Letters are in a String

Tags: c#, wpf, string, letter

I am making a Hangman Game in C# in WPF, and I am wondering if there is a way to check what letters are in a string so that if a letter is choosen the program can determine if the letter is in the chosen word or not.
Ex.

```
String StackOverFlow; //Sample String

//If Letter "A" is chosen,
private void AButt_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
//What Would I Put Here?
}
```

Comment: Since it's hangman, did you also want to know the placement(s) of any found letters, or simply whether or not the letter is in the word?

Comment: `char[] letters = StackOverflow.ToCharArray();` gives you an array of chars, which you can use to determine if the "selected" letter is in that array or not. I put "selected" in quotes because you haven't specified how you're getting the user input. Through Console? a TextBox?

Comment: @programmer93 User input is comimg from a textbox being clicked, with the specific letter, in this case an "A"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if a string contains a character in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879774/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-character-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Contains()`, but that is going to be case sensitive. Hangman is not.

The easiest way to handle that is to use `IndexOf()` instead:

```
if(StackOverFlow.IndexOf("A", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
{
    // Found
}
else
{
    // Not Found
}
```

Comment: Why is there a " > -1 "? I am sorry if this is a simple question, I am a noob :)

Comment: @Andrew - `IndexOf()` will return the index of the match. If not match is found (the string does not contain the character that you're checking for), it will return -1.

Comment: You could use `.Tolower()` or `.ToUpper()` on both input and original string to "force" case insensitiveness (case callousy?)

Comment: @Renan - You could, but that wouldn't take culture into account. Using one of the Framework methods that properly handles culture is the preferred method.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx):

```
StackOverFlow.Contains("A");
```

If you also want to know where in the word the letter first appears, you can use [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx):

```
StackOverFlow = "EXAMPLE"
StackOverFlow.IndexOf("A"); //returns 2
StackOverFlow.IndexOf("B"); //returns -1 because it is not present
```

Comment: Also note that this will only return the _first_ index of the found character. For example, searching for "l" in "Hello World" should return `{2, 3, 9}`, not just `2` if this is needed for hangman.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [String.Contais method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx). And don't create one event handler for each letter - create only one which checks what letter was input, then do something according to it existing in the string or not.

Comment: Yes, it is very redundant, but I am new, so I want to keep it simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ToLower() first to tackle case-sensitivity:
    `StackOverflow.ToLower().Contains("a")`