# Use a char to display a word

Tags: c#, string, char

new in C#, I have to write a console application for the following.

a user can input his words, the words get stored into an array,

the user gets prompted to type in a character, and the character will retrieve all the words that have that character. I have NO idea how to set the condition in the if statement and how to use the userinput to retrieve a word. Here is my try code:

```
int WCount;
string LargestWord = " ";
string SmallestWord = " ";
int vowelcount = 0;

List<string> wordsarr = new List<string>();
Console.WriteLine("How many words are you going to enter?");
WCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for (int j = 0; j < WCount; j++)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter your word");
  wordsarr.Add(Console.ReadLine());
  LargestWord = wordsarr[0];
  SmallestWord = wordsarr[1];
  string vowel = wordsarr[j].ToString();

  if(LargestWord.Length<wordsarr[j].Length)
  {
     LargestWord = wordsarr[j];
  }
  else if (SmallestWord.Length>wordsarr[j].Length)
  {
     SmallestWord = wordsarr[j];
                        }
     Console.WriteLine("Please enter a letter: ");
     char userinput = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

     if (userinput == wordsarr[j])
     {

     }
   }
```

Comment: Surely you don't want to ask the user to enter a letter on *every iteration*. Don't you want to ask for that before you start the loop?

Comment: Yes Jon, I am still learning, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("How many words are you going to enter?");
int wordCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

string[] words = new string[wordCount];
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter your word");
  words[i] = Console.ReadLine();
}

Console.WriteLine("Please enter a letter: ");
string searchChar = Console.ReadLine();

for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
  string word = words[i];
  if (word.Contains(searchChar) == true)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(word);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you feel a conditional expression reads better by adding `== true` then it should be pulled out as a local variable to give it a name that indicates its meaning. In this case, though, `word.Contains(searchChar)` reads quite well without `== true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method find invoked on wordsarr like
    `wordsarr.Find()`
Plsease check how to use find method here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/388257/Csharp-Tips-Using-delegate-in-List-Find-predicate
To check if string consists given character look here [How can I check if a string contains a character in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879774/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-character-in-c)

Comment: i may not use any functions