# Foreach Loop Checking For a Specific Character C#

Tags: c#, foreach, character

This is a really basic question but for whatever reason I can't figure this out.
The program is returning

> Error 1   Type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement

```
int i = 0;
char g = '.';
char s1 = '!';
char s2 = '?';

foreach(g in textBox1.Text)
{
   i++;
}
```

I know I repeated a variable I am trying to get g to be define as something for example to explain I will put the code to everyday language below

```
foreach(Period in textBox1.Text)
{
   i++;
}
```

//Answer there are 3 sentences in textbox 1

Comment: you need a type for the variable you are iterating with..
        foreach(var c in textBox1.Text)
        {
           i++;
        }

Comment: "Type and identifier are both required" <- the answer is right there.. `g` is an identifier, but you haven't given it a type.

Comment: If you are only checking if a `String` contains a character, you should use the `Contains()` extension method or the `IndexOf` method instead of a for loop. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879774/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-character-in-c

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(g in textBox1.Text)
```

You need to define the type for `g`

i.e.

```
foreach(char g in textBox1.Text)
```

and you have also mistakenly used the variable g twice, the foreach must have type included so one of the g's will have to change it's name

Comment: this also works `foreach(dynamic g in ListOfUnkownTypes){ DoBlahWith(g);}`

Comment: @THBBFT Please don't do that. You have the beautiful `var`.

Comment: @YoryeNathan I don't get to use the `dynamic` in my day job ... I thought I'd try it here :)

Comment: @YoryeNathan Also the `var` requires that the array be all of the same object type, the `dynamic` means i can have anything

Comment: @THBBFT Indeed, as the name `ListOfUnkownTypes` suggests.. I can't recall any case where I actually used dynamics.

Comment: I know I repeated a variable I am trying to get g to be define as something for example to explain I will put the code to everyday language below

foreach(Period in textBox1.Text)
{
   i++;
}

//Answer there are 3 sentences in textbox 1

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a foreach loop indicates that you must declare the variable type within the foreach loop. Take a look at the MSDN [implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx). You have two options:

A:

```
foreach(var c in textBox1.Text)
{
     // Boop.
}
```

B:

```
foreach(char c in textBox1.Text)
{
     // Boop.
}
```

Also answered [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1185843.aspx?Type%20and%20identifier%20are%20both%20required%20in%20a%20foreach%20statement), [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/60614/error-for-foreach-statement.html) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTq-3Qx8YCo).

Last thing, here is a better way of initializing characters:

```
char c = '\0';
```

This is what is null in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).